# Java preparedstatement cannot insert data to mysql child table with foreign key

Tags: foreign-keys

I am stuck with my parent-child mysql tables. I'm using preparedstatements in Java programming language. But I'm only successful with inserting data to my parent table. However, I can't insert data to my child table after executing another insert statement.

These are the glimpse of my tables:

tbl_patient:
ID (primary key)
patientName (primary key)
address
contact

tbl_admission:
ID (primary key)
admitDate 
patientName (foreign key referenced from tbl_patient)

When I executed my statements for inserting a new patient, it became successful and I got the result stored to my tbl_patient table. However, my problem started when I executed my preparedstatements for tbl_admission since it cannot add data to my tbl_admission. Instead, I get the following error:

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hms_mdh/admission`, CONSTRAINT `FK_admission_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`, `patientName`) REFERENCES `tbl_patient` (`ID`, `patientName`))

I really don't know what's happening here. Can I get any help? Thanks.

This is my sample sql in my child table - the admission table:

CREATE TABLE `admission` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `admitID` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `admitDate` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `patientID` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `entrance` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `doctor` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `initialDiagnosis` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `recommend` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `patientName` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_admission_1` (`ID`,`patientName`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_admission_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`, `patientName`) REFERENCES `tbl_patient` (`ID`, `patientName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='InnoDB free: 11264 kB; (`ID` `patientName`) REFER `hms_mdh/t'

And this is the parent table--the patients:

CREATE TABLE `tbl_patient` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `patientID` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `gender` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `birthday` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `chiefcomplain` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `entrance` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `patientName` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`,`patientName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: judging by the error, it looks like either you have not set FOREIGN KEY (ID, patientName) value to "tbl_admission" object that you are trying to save, or the value you are setting does not exist in "tbl_patient" table

Comment: I believe I already did that in my tables, which is why I'm confused now why it did not work out.